# Python 3 - Finding letters in same column, row or neither

Tags: python, string, list, loops, grid

```
grid = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI']
```

I have a list of letters like:

```
list = ['AD', 'GH', 'IC']
```

for example, AD are in the same column, GH in same row, and IC are neither. 
What way can i format a loop that checks for each one?

Comment: [What have you tried ?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Actually, IC are both in the third column.

Comment: Okay, youre right, but you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

You can first build a table from `chars` to `(row, col)`:

```
>>> table = {c:(i,j) for i, row in enumerate(grid) 
                     for j, c in enumerate(row)}
>>> table
{'A': (0, 0),
 'B': (0, 1),
 'C': (0, 2),
 'D': (1, 0),
 'E': (1, 1),
 'F': (1, 2),
 'G': (2, 0),
 'H': (2, 1),
 'I': (2, 2)}
```

Now it is easy to check for same column/row:

```
def same_row(x, table):
    c1, c2 = x
    return table[c1][0] == table[c2][0]

def same_column(x, table):
    c1, c2 = x
    return table[c1][1] == table[c2][1]

def neither(x, table):
    return (not same_column(x, table)) and (not same_row(x, table))
```

Some checks:

```
>>> same_column('AD', table)
True
>>> same_row('GH', table)
True
>>> same_row('IC', table)
False
>>> neither('IB', table)
True
```